# Generate providers from attributes that don't exist until run time

Tags: chef-infra

I have created two cookbooks, one that evaluates the physical array controllers and configures, partitions, luks_encrypts, mkfs and mounts the drives to /data/1, /data/2, /data/3, etc...  This works really well on a new machine and puts the hardware in a state we are looking for no matter how many drives there are or what their sizes are.

I also have a simple cassandra cookbook that installs an fpm version of cassandra, runs a template of the cassandra.yaml and creates the data directories depending on what drives are mounted to /data/1 /data/2 /data/3 etc...
done similar to:

```
# attributes file
default[:datadirs] = []
Dir.foreach("/data") do |drives|
  next if drives.match(/^\.\.?$)
  if system "/bin/mountpoint /data/#{drives}>/dev/null" then
    default[:cassandra][:data_dirs].push( "/data/#{drives}/cassandra/data" )
  end
end

# recipe
node[:cassandra][:data_dirs].each do |data_dir|
  directory "#{data_dir}" do
    owner "cassandra"
    group "cassandra"
    mode 0750
    action :create
    recursive true
  end
end
```

Of course this is getting generated at compile time when nothing is in /data.  The disks cookbook runs and populates `/data/#` however, the cassandra cookbook wont work unless there is a way to regerate the recipe after the disk cookbook has completed.  Running chef-solo a second time gets things into a proper state.

Is there a better way to create the directories?  I think I can use the lazy attribute assignment to make my template work, but the directory creation is giving me hell.

Comment: In my opinion a good chef cookbook should try and avoid the temptation to become a script.... Is there any reason why you can't declare up front the number of directories your cookbook must manage? Why does chef have to discover this information at run-time (which is the source of your problems)? For example could you hold the information in something like a databag? Just asking.

Comment: This seems like an attempt to convert a bash script into a Chef script, rather than re-analyzing the problem and finding an idempotent solution, as Mark pointed out.

Comment: You can absolutely do this with lazy attribute evaluation (happens during execution instead of compile time). I disagree with the comments above, there are tons of use cases for something like this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633509/is-there-any-way-to-delay-a-resources-attribute-resolution-until-the-execute

Comment: So the use case being that, a fresh physical system (remember those?) doesn't have the storage array configured, I have a cookbook that sees what drives are in the server, configures the array, partitions the disks, encrypts them with cryptsetup, puts a filesystem on it, and mounts it.  The number of disks varies depending on the cluster node so I don't know what it is until after the disk cookbook runs.  I did find a solution I did like with the lazy attribute for the configuration template and using a supscribes to listen to the mount options and create the data directories.